# Comparing dateutil.relativedelta

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a '>' comparison between two relativedeltas:

```
if(relativedelta(current_date, last_activity_date) > relativedelta(minutes=15)):
```

Here is the output from the debugger window in Eclipse:

[image: debug window]

One of the relativedeltas is only 15 minutes-- far smaller than the other one. Why does this comparison return false and not true as expected? What would be a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dateutil.relativedelta` doesn't implement `__cmp__` sensibly, so instances can't be compared.   There's an [open bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/969928) on the issue; the argument that it doesn't make sense to say whether 29 days or 1 month is greater, and that therefore the whole thing falls back on python's default comparisons seems a bit flimsy to me, but that's just an opinion.

Depending on what you're actually doing, using `datetime.timedelta` may be a better solution.